# How does speaker in "ROBOCOPP B A S U Ealarm SOS Personal Alarm" works?

Tags: amplifier, speakers, power-amplifier

I was working on a project which required producing a sound with more than 125 DBs...then I found this device in market which claims of producing 130DBs although to my knowledge it produces around 110DBs od sound still pretty high for a small speaker. I'm attaching a video link related to the device.

[image: the speaker]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8daQrb4scmc

Can some please explain to me how such a small speaker is able to produce such loud sound?

Comment: Cross posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481599/207455

Comment: The item circled with blue looks like a battery holder. It also looks like a piezoelectric speaker would be enclosed in the black plastic. They are very loud and efficent when operated at the resonant frequency. Used in fire alarms commonly.

Comment: If you check the cross post, the OP wants the components, not how it works...

Comment: The "cross post" is on hold so it is effectively NOT a functional cross-post any more.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 5 hours later from when I noticed...

Comment: Sorry for the cross post...i was confused where exactly to post so i posted at both the the places

Comment: @Justme thanks for the name "piezoelectric speaker"